# German phrase for something going wrong during a demo?

Tags: phrase, phrase-request

Several years ago I worked in Germany and discussed a phrase in German which doesn't really translate to English well.

Basically, the phrase was something like, "things will always go wrong during a demonstration" - but I cannot remember it. It was also considerably more elegant.

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphys_Gesetz

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure I ever heard a complete saying about this, but usually Germans will make a reference to the **"Vorführeffekt"** in a situation like this.
It pretty literally translates to *"demo effect" and means just that: that demonstrations in themselves have a tendency to go wrong.

Note that this also includes demonstrations of negative things, i.e. trying to reproduce an error when your IT person is watching. This may well be the commonest situation when people use the term.

Comment: Yes! I think this is what I was remembering.

Comment: Or even shorter: Demoeffekt.

Comment: @divby0 Is Demoeffekt even a german word? I never heard that before.

Comment: @Timbo Even if it's not in dictionary, *Demo* is a word and *Effekt* is a word, and so is *Demoeffekt* a valid German word. If it makes sense or if you need this word at all, is a different question.

Comment: @Timbo, the first time I heard it was in Zürich, admittedly in an environment full of American expats.

Comment: @divby0 Why bring up a made-up word if there is one (*Vorführeffekt*) that's well understood and very common in German?

Comment: One could add that because the formation of the Word *Vorführeffekt* is analoguous to scientifically proven physical effects like e.g. the "Hall effect" it gives the impression that it is a fundamental law of nature, so it's bound to happen.